# What is the syntax for running a spatial query in H2?

Tags: h2

I am looking at using an embedded H2 database in some GIS processing tasks. I noticed on their site that they support JTS geometries and spatial indices:

http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_index
http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html#geometry_type

I have however been unable to find a query using a geometry / bounding box. Does H2 have something like SDO_FILTER in Oracle ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96630/sdo_operat.htm#BJAFBCFC )? If not, have I misunderstood the purpose of this functionality?

I understand there is a seperate spatial plugin for H2 ( http://www.h2gis.org/ ) but can simple spatial queries by made without this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently spatial query using only h2 is limited to the filtering of rows using geometries bounding box.

## Spatial features

When [JTS Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) jar is provided H2 is able to handle geometry type and spatial index.

Download [JTS 1.13](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/vividsolutions/jts/1.13/jts-1.13.jar) and place it in the h2 bin directory.

Then edit h2.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
dir=$(dirname "$0")
java -cp "$dir/h2-1.4.178.jar:jts-1.13.jar:$H2DRIVERS:$CLASSPATH" org.h2.tools.Console "$@"
```

Run the sh, the web console will be opened.

Here the SQL to create a spatial table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE GEOTABLE( GID SERIAL, THE_GEOM GEOMETRY);
INSERT INTO GEOTABLE(THE_GEOM) VALUES ('POINT(500 505)');
INSERT INTO GEOTABLE(THE_GEOM) VALUES ('LINESTRING(550 551, 525 512, 565 566)');
INSERT INTO GEOTABLE(THE_GEOM) VALUES ('POLYGON ((550 521, 580 540, 570 564, 512 566, 550 521))');
```

In order to create a spatial index(RTREE):

```sql
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX GEOTABLE_SPATIALINDEX ON GEOTABLE(THE_GEOM);
```

The `&&` operator is like the PostGIS one. It will do a geometry **envelope** intersection test:

```sql
SELECT * FROM GEOTABLE WHERE THE_GEOM && 'POLYGON ((490 490, 536 490, 536 515, 490 515, 490 490))'
```

The evidence of spatial index usage:

```sql
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM GEOTABLE WHERE THE_GEOM && 'POLYGON ((490 490, 536 490, 536 515, 490 515, 490 490))'
```

The resut is :

```
PUBLIC.GEOTABLE_SPATIALINDEX: THE_GEOM && 'POLYGON ((490 490, 536 490, 536 515, 490 515, 490 490))' WHERE INTERSECTS(THE_GEOM, 'POLYGON ((490 490, 536 490, 536 515, 490 515, 490 490))')
```

The spatial index is stored on disk if the table is not a memory table. Otherwise it will be stored in memory.